# Can I increase the maximum effective range of an accelerometer by rotating it?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer

I've been looking for an absolute orientation IMU (usually 9 axis, with accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer) that can measure high g-loads in one direction (max ~20 g). However, the highest rating I can find is around 16g. I am aware that there are accelerometers with higher capabilities, but not of one within a single-chip IMU.

However - since the accelerations only appear significantly in one direction, I was thinking it I could rotate the chip by 45 degrees, so that the acceleration is "partially taken on" by two axes, giving me 16 * sqrt(2) ~= 22.5g (sufficient for my application).

Would this work in practice?

Comment: I think you can even make it take the load in three axis.

Comment: 20g is not much... Have you looked at digikey? I just did a 2000g design last week.

Comment: @MadHatter I am aware of accelerometers with extremely high gs, but none that are already coupled with gyroscopes within a single-chip IMU

Comment: @Jeroen3 I could - but 2 axes would be enough and in terms of mounting, I would need to put the PCB on a slant for 3 axes whereas I just need to rotate the chip for 2 axes.